# Javafx Tabpane - Reversing the scrolling direction

Tags: java, javafx, scroll, tabs, horizontal-scrolling

it's my first time asking a question so I will try to do my best.

In my javafx application, I have a tabpane and I want to reverse the scrolling direction of this tabpane. Currently, when I scroll up it goes to the left and when I scroll down it goes to the right. I want this to be reversed.

I tried messing with the TabPaneSkin class but I couldn't do it.

It seems like this piece of code from TabPaneSkin.java is setting up this behaviour:

```
// support for mouse scroll of header area (for when the tabs exceed
// the available space).
// Scrolling the mouse wheel downwards results in the tabs scrolling left (i.e. exposing the right-most tabs)
// Scrolling the mouse wheel upwards results in the tabs scrolling right (i.e. exposing th left-most tabs)
addEventHandler(ScrollEvent.SCROLL, (ScrollEvent e) -> {
    Side side = getSkinnable().getSide();
    side = side == null ? Side.TOP : side;
    switch (side) {
            default:
            case TOP:
            case BOTTOM:
                 setScrollOffset(scrollOffset + e.getDeltaY());
                 break;
            case LEFT:
            case RIGHT:
                setScrollOffset(scrollOffset - e.getDeltaY());
                break;
    }
});
```

It's kinda obvious that we need to change the + and minus signs there but how exactly? It looks like there's no way to reach to method (it's inside a TabPaneHeader instance and that instance is private with to getter method).

Any ideas about doing this?
Thanks.

Comment: You could decorate the `EventDispatcher` of the `TabPane` to modify (or at least copy-and-modify) any `ScrollEvent` and negate its `deltaY`. All other exceptions you would just forward to the real `EventDispatcher` without modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by doing this: (I followed Slaw's suggestion)

```
public static void reverseTabPaneScrollingDirection(TabPane tabPane) {
    EventDispatcher originalDispatcher = tabPane.getEventDispatcher();
    tabPane.setEventDispatcher(new EventDispatcher() {
        @Override
        public Event dispatchEvent(Event event, EventDispatchChain tail) {
            if (event instanceof ScrollEvent) {
                ScrollEvent e = (ScrollEvent) event;
                ScrollEvent reversedEvent = new ScrollEvent(
                        e.getEventType(), e.getX(), e.getY(), e.getScreenX(),
                        e.getScreenY(), e.isShiftDown(), e.isControlDown(), e.isAltDown(),
                        e.isMetaDown(), e.isDirect(), e.isInertia(), e.getDeltaX(),
                        -e.getDeltaY(), // reverse it
                        e.getTotalDeltaX(),
                        -e.getTotalDeltaY(), // reverse it
                        e.getMultiplierX(), e.getMultiplierY(), e.getTextDeltaXUnits(),
                        e.getTextDeltaX(), e.getTextDeltaYUnits(), e.getTextDeltaY(),
                        e.getTouchCount(), e.getPickResult()
                );

                return originalDispatcher.dispatchEvent(reversedEvent, tail);
            }

            return originalDispatcher.dispatchEvent(event, tail);
        }
    });
}
```

I would like to see your opinions about my solution. :)
It was also my first time using EventDispatchers directly so I would like to know if I did something wrong. It seems to be functioning well but doesn't hurt to ask :)

Comment: Looks pretty much like what I had in mind :) Only thing I would change is to use [this constructor](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/ScrollEvent.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.Object,javafx.event.EventTarget,javafx.event.EventType,double,double,double,double,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,double,double,double,double,javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent.HorizontalTextScrollUnits,double,javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent.VerticalTextScrollUnits,double,int,javafx.scene.input.PickResult)) instead to make sure the source and target don't get lost.

Comment: And just as a quality-of-life thing, if you're using a recent enough version of Java then you can get rid of that manual cast to `ScrollEvent` and instead just use `if (event instanceof ScrollEvent e) { ... }`.

Comment: Thank you so much I will consider applying those changes as well. :)